# Why is my range slider exceeding my desired maximum width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-variables

I created a range slider using just a single `div` with `::pseudo` elements since I cannot access `::pseudo` directly with `JavaScript` I took help of `CSS` variables. But there are certain problems I faced along and was not able to solve.

**With `max-width`**

```js
const range = document.querySelector(".range");

function setRange(event) {
  const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();

  range.style.setProperty(
    "--progress",
    `${(event.clientX / rect.width) * 100}%`
  );
}

range.addEventListener("pointerdown", (event) => {
  range.classList.add("active");
  range.setPointerCapture(event.pointerId);
  setRange(event);

  range.addEventListener("pointermove", setRange);

  range.addEventListener(
    "pointerup",
    (event) => {
      range.classList.remove("active");
      range.releasePointerCapture(event.pointerId);
      range.removeEventListener("pointermove", setRange);
    }, {
      once: true
    }
  );
});
```

```css
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KunalTanwar/normalize/css/normalize.inter.min.css";
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.range {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0.25rem;
  max-width: 450px;
  border-radius: 60rem;
  background-color: rgba(120, 120, 128, 0.2);
}

.range::before,
.range::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.range::before {
  width: var(--progress);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: #007aff;
}

.range::after {
  top: 50%;
  cursor: grab;
  width: 1.75rem;
  height: 1.75rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  left: var(--progress);
  background-color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0px 6px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.range.active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<div class="range"></div>
```

**Without `max-width`**

```js
const range = document.querySelector(".range");

function setRange(event) {
  const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();

  range.style.setProperty(
    "--progress",
    `${(event.clientX / rect.width) * 100}%`
  );
}

range.addEventListener("pointerdown", (event) => {
  range.classList.add("active");
  range.setPointerCapture(event.pointerId);
  setRange(event);

  range.addEventListener("pointermove", setRange);

  range.addEventListener(
    "pointerup",
    (event) => {
      range.classList.remove("active");
      range.releasePointerCapture(event.pointerId);
      range.removeEventListener("pointermove", setRange);
    }, {
      once: true
    }
  );
});
```

```css
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KunalTanwar/normalize/css/normalize.inter.min.css";
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.range {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0.25rem;
  border-radius: 60rem;
  background-color: rgba(120, 120, 128, 0.2);
}

.range::before,
.range::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.range::before {
  width: var(--progress);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: #007aff;
}

.range::after {
  top: 50%;
  cursor: grab;
  width: 1.75rem;
  height: 1.75rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  left: var(--progress);
  background-color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0px 6px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.range.active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<div class="range"></div>
```

**My Approach**

What my initial thought was that I will put an `if` condition inside `setRange()` function :

```js
function setRange(event) {
  const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (
    !(window.getComputedStyle(range).getPropertyValue("--progress") > "100%")
  ) {
    range.style.setProperty(
      "--progress",
      `${(event.clientX / rect.width) * 100}%`
    );
  }
}
```

But the above code is not working after first `pointerdown` although when I am console logging the if condition it is working just fine.

I also tried :

```js
if (!(parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(range).getPropertyValue('--progress')) > 100)) {
  range.style.setProperty('--progress', `${(event.clientX / rect.width) * 100}%`)
}
```

and again after reaching 100% I am not able to move it back to below 100% in simple words I can't move the slider after reaching 100%.

There are 2 main questions

1. Why after setting `max-width` the range slider not working like it should.
2. Why the `if` condition I put inside `setRange()` working on `console.log()` not inside DOM?
3. How can I set `max-value` of `var(--progress)` so it should not increase beyond 100% ?

**P.S** - suggest an appropriate title for this question!